# Find the midpoint of an array in c, why do we use (end + start)/2 ? Please explain

Tags: c, arrays

I want to find the midpoint of an array in C say: `{2,5,7,23,1,8,3,8,2}` with an expected result of 1. Also if the array is even in the case of `{2,6,9,231,62,3}`, I expect to get any of the middle values - `9` or `231` in this case.

I am completely unsure how to go about this.

Comment: Usually, `length/2` is the midpoint.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, so it's not clear what help you need. Please at least post some code with slot where the code to find the midpoint would go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your problem description, regardless of whether your array has even or odd number of elements, the middle element index is always length/2.

```
int main() {
  int a[] = {2,5,7,23,1,8,3,8,2};
  //Figure out the size of the array 
   int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
   printf("The mid point is %d", a[n/2]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. I don't know why i got the down votes though. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't downvote your question. But don't worry. It happens sometimes.

Comment: `sizeof(a)` here is the size of a pointer. `arrayMidpoint()` does not generate an acceptable result.

Comment: @delali, did you check if this code works? I am skeptical as an array passed as parameter is treated as pointer. So `sizeof(a)` imo should return size of a pointer and not suze of the array. But i do not have a computer nearby to test it. Please check.

Comment: @chux, you are right. An array in the function argument is treated as a pointer and hence `sizeof` on it returns the size of a pointer, not the total size of all the elements of the original array. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @inquisitive yeah. I realized that problem and fixed it accordingly. I only wanted to know the method for getting an array midpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

- Find the size `n` of the array. Usually done by `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`.
- Index `array[n/2]` to find midpoint.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE(x) (sizeof x / sizeof x[0])

int main(void) {
    int array1[] = {2,5,7,23,1,8,3,8,2};
    int array2[] = {2,6,9,231,62,3};

    printf("First midpoint = %d\n", array1[SIZE(array1)/2]);
    printf("Second midpoint = %d\n", array2[SIZE(array2)/2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
First midpoint = 1
Second midpoint = 231
```